# Swagger API endpoint with Next.js application

Tags: next.js, swagger, endpoint

I have created post API in swagger endpoint, the purpose of this post request to send email notification when user submit request, my challenge came when I try to implement swagger endpoint with my next app, how I setup this connection?

I have spent sometime to search for solution, is next-swagger-doc is solution?

This is the Post API request body:

```json
{
"From": "string",
"To": "Unknown Type: String\[\]",
"Cc": "Unknown Type: String\[\]",
"Subject": "string",
"Body": "string",
"IsBodyHtml": "true",
"Attachments": "Unknown Type: String\[\]"
}
```